# Что надо поправить в коде чтобы кнопки Яндекс.Поделиться снова выглядели правильно?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Этот код перестал работать:

```
<style>
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon {
    height: 34px!important;
    width: 34px!important;}
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__counter {
    font-size: 18px!important;
    padding: 5px 10px!important;}
</style>
```

-

сейчас размер иконок уменьшен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надо увеличить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить в стиль background-repeat: no-repeat;

```
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__counter {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    padding: 5px 10px!important;}
```

Или

```
.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__counter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    padding: 5px 10px!important;}
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант, но не сработало...